# How to do extract multiple rows based on matching year plus 2 previous years from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am working with sports stats data and want to extract stats from past 3 years. If I have a dataframe with player and year, how can I extract rows from another dataframe that has matching player, and same year and the previous 2?

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['ABC',2018,5,2,3],
['ABC',2017,52,21,31],['ABC',2016,15,12,13],
['ABC',2015,25,22,3]],
columns=['Player','Year','GS','G','MP'])

df1=

Player Year GS G  MP
ABC    2018  5  2  3
ABC    2017 52 21 31
ABC    2016 15 12 13
ABC    2015 25 22 3
```

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["ABC",2017]], columns=['Player','Year'])

df2=

Player Year
ABC    2017
```

this should result in

```py
Player Year GS G  MP
ABC    2017 52 21 31
ABC    2016 15 12 13
ABC    2015 25 22 3
```

Eventually I want to do summations but extracting this make that much easier. Is there a pythonic way to do this using merge or filter?

Comment: I don't see any colum(s) extracted from `df2`. What is your goal eventually. Is there more data in df2?

Comment: to sum the columns and then update the 2018 row with the result. This wlil need to be done for all of df1 that has a matching player and year in df2 (df2 has more data, sorry if that wasn't obvious)

Answer (score 0):

`merge` on 'Player' then filter the year range after:

```
res = df1.merge(df2, on='Player', suffixes=['', '_r'])
res = res.loc[res.Year.between(res.Year_r-2, res.Year_r)].drop(columns='Year_r')

print(res)
#  Player  Year  GS   G  MP
#1    ABC  2017  52  21  31
#2    ABC  2016  15  12  13
#3    ABC  2015  25  22   3
```

---

Or if 'Player' is not duplicated in `df2`, map to a Series and then mask with a Boolean Series:

```
s = df1.Player.map(df2.set_index('Player').Year)
df1[df1.Year.between(s-2, s)]

#  Player  Year  GS   G  MP
#1    ABC  2017  52  21  31
#2    ABC  2016  15  12  13
#3    ABC  2015  25  22   3
```

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern is to specify what values to filter on with the form `df1[df1.Column == value]`.  You can combine multiple as follows:

```
years  = [(df2.Year.values[0] - j) for j in range(3)]
player = df2.Player.values[0]
result = df1[(df1.Player == player) & (df1.Year.isin(years))]
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good! But also this should work :)

```
# to be safe, at first, sort the DataFrames
df1.sort_index(inplace=True)
df2.sort_index(inplace=True)

# prepare the Masks   Boolean responses
check_1 = df1["Player"] == df2["Player"].to_list()[0]
# to be safe use int() to get integers in the for loop
years_list = (int(df2["Year"].tolist()[0])-i for i in range(0, 3))
check_2 = df1.Year.map(int).isin(years_list)

# apply the masks
print(df1[check_1 & check_2])
```

Anyway not necessarily you need a DataFrame to store the matching "Player" and the matching "Year".
Two lists or even variables would be even better, since it seems you have not set real columns in your df2, as Erfan noticed in the comment under your question.